# Retrieve values from two tables based on time

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables like below

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users 
(
   serial  INTEGER NOT NULL,
   userid INTEGER, 
   time    INTEGER,
   name TEXT NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (serial) 
); 

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS polls 
(
   pollid TEXT NOT NULL, 
   name TEXT NOT NULL,
   userid  INTEGER NOT NULL, 
   time     INTEGER NOT NULL, 
   PRIMARY KEY (pollid) 
);
```

When a user logged in I will have userid, I am trying to get polls of the logged in user and polls created after other users who created their accounts after this user from polls table with `labels you polled`, `others polled`.

I am here but don't know how to proceed further

```
SELECT pollid, name FROM polls AS P JOIN users AS U ON ......
```

Please help me on this. If I want to access only the current user polls I think I don't need to join tables but below query will work

```
SELECT pollid, name FROM polls where userid=inputUserid
```

But query is dependent on two tables.

Comment: SELECT pollid, name FROM polls AS P JOIN users AS U ON u.userid = p.userid

Comment: @Almazini Please read my question again, I would like to get also other users polls of accounts created after the retrieving user account.

Comment: So then we can try another approach. 
SELECT *
FROM polls AS P 
WHERE time => (SELECT Time FROM Users AS U WHERE U.UserID = @youruser)

Comment: @Almazini But this will consider the polls time, I would like to consider user accounts created time or even serial id of users is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have understood logic correctly:

```
SELECT *
FROM polls as P
WHERE userid IN (SELECT userID FROM users WHERE UserID >= @YourUSerID);
```

In Sub-query you will select your user and all users which were created after. 
In main query you select all polls for users in subquery.

Join will also work:

```
SELECT *
FROM polls as P
INNER JOIN users as U ON p.userID = u.userID
WHERE u.userid >= @youruser
```

In case UserID is not incremeted:

sub-sub-query finds time when user was created;
sub-query finds all users created after time from sub-sub-query;
query finds all polls for users from sub-query:

```
SELECT *
FROM polls
WHERE userID IN (SELECT UserID 
                 FROM users
                 WHERE time >= (SELECT time
                                FROM Users
                                WHERE userID = @YourUser)
```

Comment: Thanks. Will try this and let you know whether it's working or not.

Comment: In second query you are checking only one user, not all am I correct? `p.userID = u.userID`

Comment: no, first it joins two tables by userID column. Than in WHERE clause it filters only users with the same or bigger user ID.

Comment: That's beautiful answer. Could you please also add time based logic as I have mentioned in my Question. The problem I understood now from your query is, userId is not auto incremented ID, it's manual given id. Only serial is auto incremented id. So instead of `u.userid => @youruser` it should be based on time or serial number of the users

Comment: I am getting error when i am trying to execute the same using webSQL `"could not prepare statement (1 near ">": syntax error)"`

Comment: @Exception you already know the trick. it should be >= instead of =>